# Aggregation in Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I use SpringData+ mongoDB. Is it possible to do it in SporingData(I know, how to doi it in shell)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SpringData's alternative to the aggregation framework is the [group operation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.group). You can execute group operations as a method of the [MongoTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mongoOps.getCollection("yourCollection").aggregate( ... )
```

As aggregate framework is not yet supported.